# 「YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT」画面中のyoutube表示

Tags: android, youtube-player-api

YoutubeAPIの利用には、Youtubeロゴやアイコンを表示する必要があると認識しておりますが、

これは、Android Player API の「YouTubePlayer.PlayerStyle.DEFAULT」スタイルの
再生位置を表すプログレスバー横に表示されるYoutubeロゴでも条件満たすものなのでしょうか・・。

実装の対象は、Android向けアプリで別ウインドウで再生画面が開き動作するように検討しています。

以下のBranding Guidelinesにあるものと少し違っており、不安になり質問させていただきました。
https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/branding-guidelines

Comment: YouTube(Google)に質問してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。

Googleさんに直接に質問したいとも思っているのですが、

APIのデベロッパーズサイトの「サポート」でも
『Stack Overflow』の記載しかありませんでしたし

その窓口が分からず・・・こちらに質問をあげておりました。
もう少し、色々、Googleさんに問い合わせる方法を調べてみます。

ありがとうございました。

Comment: 最悪、こちらで何でも受け付けてくれそうですね．返信なさそうですが...最後の手段ということで。
via: https://www.youtube.com/t/contact_us?hl=ja&gl=JP

YouTube, LLC
901 Cherry Ave.
San Bruno, CA 94066
USA
FAX: +1 650-253-0001

Comment: そうですね。。頂いたURLの問い合わせはYoutubeへ登録の動画コンテンツに関したものが対象というように見ていましたが・・最終手段として有りかもしれませんね。検討してみます。ありがとうございます。